# Sketch 49, unable to zoom/fit to width using Mirror?

Tags: sketch-app, prototyping

Since updating to [Sketch 49](https://www.sketchapp.com/updates/), I am unable to zoom in on my phone when displaying the artboards using Mirror. Does anybody else experience this problem too? Does anybody know if there is a solution?

Resolved, see answer.

Answer (score 1):

Found the [answer](https://sketchapp.com/docs/prototyping/previewing#prototyping-and-artboard-presets) after shooting Sketch a tweet!